# Cannot install USB driver for my Samsung Galaxy S Plus

Tags: usb, drivers, android, device-manager

I cannot run my Android Application on my Samsung Galaxy S Plus. I followed [the guidelines](http://developer.android.com/sdk/oem-usb.html) on the Android Developer site.

The first time I tried this I was able to select Device Manager and in the right hand pane I could see the other devices option from which I selected my phone. From here windows "searched the Internet" to find and install the software (USB driver) for my phone. It told me it did so successfully but then I went to run my project from Eclipse and it still does not recognise my phone!

When I tried to perform the operation a second time I could not see "other devices" in the right hand pane of my computer managers window after clicking on device manager. Why am I not seeing other devices or my phone when selecting device manager?

Answer (score 2):

I had to install the [Kies](http://www.samsung.com/us/kies/) app and it came with the drivers for my GS